# iCarousel shows with an offset of 1/2 heigh and 1/2 width

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, indexing, icarousel

The view has an offset of 1/2 view.width and 1/2 view.heigth and I don't know why. (I can't upload an image since i have not reputation enough)

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label;
    UILabel *label2;
    UILabel *label3;
    UILabel *label4;
    UILabel *label5;

    UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mockUp"];
    view = [viewController.view viewWithTag:999];
    label=(UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:109];
    label2=(UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:110];
    label3=(UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:111];
    label4=(UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:112];
    label5=(UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:113];

    CGRect  Frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
    view.frame = Frame;

    label.text = [[listOfCompaniesCalledPortfolio objectAtIndex:index]nameOfTheCompanie];
    label2.text = [[listOfCompaniesCalledPortfolio objectAtIndex:index]sector];
    label3.text = [[listOfCompaniesCalledPortfolio objectAtIndex:index]companyLocation];
    label4.text = [[listOfCompaniesCalledPortfolio objectAtIndex:index]busDescription];
    label5.text = [[listOfCompaniesCalledPortfolio objectAtIndex:index]founders];

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you implemented these iCarousel delegates:

```
- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
   {
     return 200.0; //your expected width
   }

- (CGFloat)carouselItemHeight:(iCarousel *)carousel
   {
     return 200.0; //your expected height
   }
```

Comment: The size of the carousel is the one of the view I instanciate (viewWithTag:999) so is ok. The problem is that it looks that all the view has an offset..

Comment: can you upload or link a snap-shot?